# How can I "git push" when I face Error : error: failed to push some refs to "my remote git address"

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a problem that push command doesn't work.

First, for create remote repository in git-hub, I did some things that can push my .c file. It works well at first.

But I changed some codes and I entered in terminal git add & git commit to push my c file.

finally I entered git push, and I faced error about this.

**! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'repository address'**

I saw many solutions in google, so I already did 'git pull'. but it doesn't work.

my error

[image]

I attach capture, which contains git status and git push error.

Comment: Read the git status. You have not finished the merge you are in the middle of.

Answer (score 0):

Run git commit before pushing.

Comment: I did but it show me "File exists." . Thank you for comment.